# Why PPID is not shown as a part of PID in

Tags: unix, ps

Running ps -f command

[image]

I have been trying to search everywhere but was not able to find that why PPID is not a part of PID? i mean in the above screenshot we have a PID 1166, its parent PID or PPID is 1163 but, there is also a PID 1272 whose PPID is 1238.

There should also be entries for 1238 in the PID, why are they not there?

Answer (score 0):

try below 2 ps commands, hope that is what you are looking for.
ps -efj
or
ps -efww